# How do I get a list of all Users and their associated UserRoles efficiently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to populate a view model with User data that includes a list of the user's associated roles. Currently, my method is as follows:

```
[EnableQuery]
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Get()
{
    var clientId = this.GetClientId();
    var users = this.UserManager.Users.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId).ProjectTo<UserViewModel>().ToList();

    foreach (UserViewModel user in users)
    {
        user.UserRoles = this.UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
    }

    return users;
}
```

Is there a better way to perform this operation? I cannot create a Linq query because EF will not allow me to create a class for the AspNetUserRoles table, and it will not allow me to edit the AspNetUsers table directly - so I am using the UserManager to get the results instead.

Comment: You don't need to create classes - they already exist. var myUsersAndRoles = context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).ToList();

Comment: i second @SteveGreene

Comment: Thank you @SteveGreene, that is exactly what I was looking for!

I can mark your response as an answer if you'd like to submit the same post but as an answer :)